# PDF Filename Always 0 when viewing

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-7

I have created a function where a user can go to this link and he can view his bill in PDF. It's working but the name is always [image: 0]. Here's my code:

```
function export_view($account_number_id, $subaccount_number_id){
    $pdf = $this->pdf($account_number_id, $subaccount_number_id);
    $filename = $pdf->name.'.pdf';
    $path = public_path($pdf->path);

    $response = Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    return $response;
}
```

I also did manual pdf filename to see if it's the issue but it's the same. When I download it in my local, the name is there. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `$this->pdf()` method renders the pdf from a blade template?
You can set the name of the PDF document in the html title metatag:

```html
<head>
  <title>{{ $invoice->number }}</title>
</head>
```